# what all data needs to be deleted to make it equivalent to application uninstall

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, data-synchronization

I came into a very strange problem. In my application, there is a synch process that runs every 3000 milliseconds and synchs the data from `local database(SQlite)` to server database.

Now when I create any record, the synch process runs and the data is synched to server.
When I logs out, I deletes the local database and when I logs in, the synch process runs 
and I get the data from server database back.

**Problem Scenario:**

**1)** I creates a record and it get synched to remote server database.

**2)** I logs out and logs in back. I see the created record in my UI.

**3)** I again logs out and logs in back. Now, I don't see the record that I created at step 1.

**4)** I repeats the step 2 logout and login and then sometimes I see record and sometimes not.

**5)** I uninstall the application completely. I reinstall it again. Now I login back and see my created record.

**6)** I repeat step 2 logout and login and then I always see the record created at step 1.

At click of logout, I am clearing all the shared preferences and all my database file.

**My question is:**

Is there something missing that I didn't deleted on logout click which caused such behavior because after application uninstall, the synch process is always right and I see my created records always.